# SECURE flag not appearing for JSESSIONID cookie

Tags: amazon-web-services, spring-security

Application is deployed on AWS and serves on port 80 and ELB forwards that 80 to 443. Spring security is used for session which creates cookie with secure flag set.  When I hit the application host name I could see that secure flag is set as shown below.

curl -I target_hostname

Set-Cookie: JSESSIONID=XXXXXXXX; Path=/; Secure; HttpOnly

But when i directly hit EC2 IP (using curl) I could see that secure flag is not set.

curl -I target_ec2_ip

Set-Cookie: JSESSIONID=XXXXXXXX; Path=/; HttpOnly

Why it is happening can anyone explain?

Comment: When I hit application using IP from browser I see a cookie in chrome developer tool which is not secure but when I hit application using host name I see that secure flag is set. I am using spring security. Any suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to assume that you terminate SSL at the ELB, and you're contacting the EC2 instance directly via HTTP (port 80). In that case, the following applies:

[RFC 6265](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6265#section-5.4):

> If the cookie's secure-only-flag is true, then the request-uri's scheme must denote a "secure" protocol (as defined bythe user agent).
>
> NOTE: The notion of a "secure" protocol is not defined by this document.  Typically, user agents consider a protocol secure if the protocol makes use of transport-layer security, such as SSL or TLS.

The [MDN doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Set-Cookie) is more explicit:

> Insecure sites (http:) can't set cookies with the "secure" directive anymore (new in Chrome 52+ and Firefox 52+).

Comment: So do you mean that even though secure flag is set it will not appear in above scenario? Also in this case cookie can be stolen by MITM attack. How to prevent that?